# count the number of occurrences of a string in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, count

I want to calcutae the number of occurrences of a string in a particular node in XML document using XSLT. 
Consider this example

```
 <mainNode>
<book>
    <price> 100 </price>
    <city> chennai </city>
    <list>
        <language> c java ruby </language>
    </list>
</book>

<book>
    <price> 200 </price>
    <city> banglore </city>
    <list>
        <language> c java </language>
    </list>
</book>

<book>
    <price> 300 </price>
    <city> delhi </city>
    <list>
        <language> java ruby </language>
    </list>
</book>
</mainNode>
```

Here I want to count the occurrences of "java"

**I Want Output like this::   java -- 3**

How to do this??? any idea???

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath expression solution. :)

Comment: Minor point, but your XML's kind of badly designed. You really should have a list of `<language>` elements, like this: `<list><language>java</language><language>ruby</language></list>` instead of having them in a space-separate list in a single element; it would have made this trivial to answer, with `count(//language[.='java'])`.

Comment: Also, you haven't listed it in an example, but could `javascript` appear in the list of languages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count(/*/*/list/language[contains(., 'java')])
```

**The complete XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     java -- <xsl:value-of select=
       "count(/*/*/list/language[contains(., 'java')]) "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<mainNode>
    <book>
        <price> 100 </price>
        <city> chennai </city>
        <list>
            <language> c java ruby </language>
        </list>
    </book>
    <book>
        <price> 200 </price>
        <city> banglore </city>
        <list>
            <language> c java </language>
        </list>
    </book>
    <book>
        <price> 300 </price>
        <city> delhi </city>
        <list>
            <language> java ruby </language>
        </list>
    </book>
</mainNode>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 java -- 3
```

**Update**:

If we are to count *all* occurences of the string -- not just all nodes that contain the string -- here's how to do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pWord" select="' java '"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vResult">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($pWord, '--- ')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($vResult)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list/language" name="countWord">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

        <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $pWord)">
            <xsl:text>X</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="countWord">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText"
                 select="concat(' ', substring-after($pText, $pWord))"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<mainNode>
    <book>
        <price> 100 </price>
        <city> chennai </city>
        <list>
            <language> c java ruby </language>
        </list>
    </book>
    <book>
        <price> 200 </price>
        <city> banglore </city>
        <list>
            <language> c java </language>
        </list>
    </book>
    <book>
        <price> 300 </price>
        <city> delhi </city>
        <list>
            <language> java java ruby </language>
        </list>
    </book>
</mainNode>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 java --- 4
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who downvoted this? It works just fine for the sample given.

Comment: This code is work well. Suppose the node language contains more than one java like, <language> java java ruby <language>. Now the count should increased by 1, but it still show 3. How to get 4?

Comment: @Sathish: This is a very different question. It would be best toas this as a separate question. It is nearing midnight where I am, so, please, expect my answer about 8hrs from now.

Comment: @ Dimitre Novatchev: ok man no probs, pls do this for me, I tried so many times. I coudnt get it. This scenario is very important for me so please try this....

Comment: @Dimitre: It's a very different answer, not a different question. The question and the title refer to counting the number of occurrences of a string, not the number of nodes that contain a string.

Comment: @Sathish: I have updated my answer to solve correctly your new problem. Enjoy :)

Comment: @Sathish: And updated it again, to make it ultimately simpler.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try this [XSL Template to count substrings](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/xsl/substring_count.html):

```
<xsl:template name="substring-count">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="substr"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string, $substr) and $string and $substr">
      <xsl:variable name="rest">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-count">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $substr)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="$substr"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$rest + 1"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Usage:

```
<xsl:call-template name="substring-count">
  <xsl:with-param name="string" select="'mary had a little lamb'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="'lamb'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but there's a typo in the usage. It should be   <xsl:with-param name="string" ....

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a `<xsl:value-of>` statement:

`count(//language[contains(concat(' ',.,' '), ' java ')])`

If your document structure is relatively static, or you have nodes called `language` elsewhere that serve another purpose, you can substitute `//language` for `/mainNode/book/list/language`.

The `concat` bit might seem a bit convoluted, but by making sure there's a space at the beginning and end of the text you're looking in, and searching for `' java '` with a space either side, you won't incorrectly include other terms that happen to include `java`, such as `javascript`.

If it's possible for 'java' to exist more than once in a node, then you'll need to use a recursive template. Here's one way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="list">
      <xsl:for-each select="//language">
        <xsl:call-template name="count">
          <xsl:with-param name="lang">java</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('java -- ',string-length($list))" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="count">
    <xsl:param name="lang" />
    <xsl:param name="text" select="text()" />
    <xsl:if test="contains(concat(' ',$text,' '),concat(' ',$lang,' '))">
      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="count">
        <xsl:with-param name="lang" select="$lang" />
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$lang)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This essentially creates a string of `0`'s, one for each occurrence of `java`, and then simply uses the length of that string.

If you have the option of using XSLT 2.0, you can create a function that counts the number of occurrences in a string, and use `<xsl:value-of select="sum(mycountfunction(//language))" />` or something similar.

As I pointed out in a comment on your question, a better design of the source XML would have helped significantly; none of this is necessary if each occurrence of a language had it's own element. Of course that may be outside your control, but if you have the option of changing that (or persuading the provider to change it) I'd strongly recommend it.

Comment: Its working good. From this code I learn function calling in XSL. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Flynn1179:::
In the above function you have passed "java" as a argument. Instead of "java" can I pass empty string like " "? How to pass the empty string or char " "?

Comment: You can, but what would the point in that? Passing an empty string will probably recurse infinitely and passing in a space will give you totally meaningless results, given that you're using a space as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_number-of-matches.html

```
count(tokenize($arg,$pattern)) - 1
```

I have answered likewise here: [Find the number of occurences of a substring in a string in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458001/find-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-xslt/44286342#44286342)