# Count specific letter combinations in a <p> element during xslt processing

Tags: xml, string, xslt, count

I need to count specific letter combinations in a xhtml file while processing it in xsl.

An example would be the words `&amp;` and `&quot;`

to count the occurrences in the `<p>` below

> ```
> <p>
>   enthroned in his gorgeous palace upon the <strike>c</strike>&amp;Capitoline
>   <strike>h</strike>&quot;H&quot;ill that a babe slumbering in a manger in the obscure hamlet of Bethlehem a remote province of Asyria
> </p>
> ```

I would expect a count of 1 for `&amp;` and a count of 2 for `&quot;`

I can use xsl 2.0 or 3.0

Scott

Comment: I have changed your `&mp;Capitoline` to `&amp;Capitoline`.

Answer (score 2):

Both `&amp;` and `&quot;` are characters, not words. You could count the number of occurrences of the  `&amp;` character in the current node using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(replace(., '[^&amp;]', ''))"/>
```

Or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(string-to-codepoints(.)[.=38])"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a simple 1.0 solution:

```
string-length(.) - string-length(translate(., '&amp;', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 4 there will be a `characters` function https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview-diff.html#func-characters so in environments where that is already supported you can do e.g.

```
let $chars := characters(.)
return
  for $char in ('"', '&amp;')
  return 'count(' || $char || '): ' || count($chars[. = $char])
```

[BaseX fiddle](https://bxfiddle.cloud.basexgmbh.de/?share=%28%27query%21%27let-E%3A%3D%20Iacters%7B.%7DJreturn2for-4%7B%22%5C%27%22%2C69%22%7D2retur*%22D%223-36%7D%3A6KDLs%5B.%20%3D-%5D5%21%27%3Cp%3E2enthroned4hiEgorgeouEpalac1upo*th1Mc709Capitoline2Mh708H8ill%20thatGbab1slumbering4Fmanger4th1obscur1hamlet%20of%20BethlehemGremot1provinc1of%20AsyriaJ7p%3E%27%7Emode%21%27XQuery%20%7BBaseX5Type%21%27xml%27%29*n%20-%20L0strike%3E1e%202%5C*%20K%7C%7C4%20i*5%7D%27%7Econtext6%20%227%3C%2F8%26quot%3B9%26amp%3BDcount%7BEsGa%20G%20FIcharJ%5CnK3%20L%24IM%3C0%01MLKJIGFED9876543210-*_).

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this, a modified version of this.
[count the number of occurrences of a string in XML using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679705/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-xml-using-xslt)
Its a generic answer to count any string and return the count.

```
   <xsl:template match="http:p">
        <xsl:variable name="ltResult" >
            <xsl:call-template name="countWord">
                <xsl:with-param name="pWord" select="'&amp;'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="string-join(text())"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="0"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="gtResult">
            <xsl:call-template name="countWord">
                <xsl:with-param name="pWord" select="'&quot;'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="string-join(text())"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="0"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:message terminate="no">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('&amp; : ', $ltResult , ' &quot; : ', $gtResult)"
                    />
                </xsl:message>
                
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="countWord">
        <xsl:param name="pWord" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="pText" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="count" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pText, $pWord)">
                <xsl:call-template name="countWord">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pWord" select="$pWord"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="concat(' ', substring-after($pText, $pWord))"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: There are much simpler methods in XSLT 2.0+, but that's not what this question is about.